# CoreData read fault, null value causing errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmutablearray, nsfetchrequest

I have an app that people are using, some users are experiencing errors which I have figured out that when I try to read from Coredata it is returning null values.

I have done some reading and found out that coredata dose some tricky stuff where it will only return the data when you need it and from what I have read this is called faulting or something. The interesting thing is, is that this error dose not happen with every device.. I think it is selective from the OS depending on memory or something.

This was the code I was using to read from coredata as well as my stack trace.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)readManuf
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]; // added to fix fault, but not working.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Manuf" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSMutableArray *manufacturerDictionaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (Manuf *manuf in fetchedObjects) {

        NSMutableDictionary *tempManufacturerDictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.hasModel forKey:@"HASMODEL"]; // error app calls over
        [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.isManufacturer forKey:@"ISMANUFACTURER"];
        [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.nicknames forKey:@"NICKNAMES"];
        [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.manufacturer forKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];
        [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.manufacturerID forKey:@"MANUFACTURERID"];

        [manufacturerDictionaryArray addObject:tempManufacturerDictionary];
    }
    return manufacturerDictionaryArray;
}
```

Heres my stack trace.

```
<_NSCallStackArray 0x155f6790>(
0   ???                                 0x0323d714 0x0 + 52680468,
1   CodeI                               0x00059ba9 main + 0,
2   CoreFoundation                      0x306488f3 <redacted> + 818,
3   CodeI                               0x000d83eb -[CoreDataController readManuf] + 1134,
4   CodeI                               0x0008c4cb -[EngineRequests GetManufacturers:CallingView:] + 806,
5   CodeI                               0x00076ddf -[VehicleSearchViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 1278,
6   UIKit                               0x3305c8f7 <redacted> + 410,
7   UIKit                               0x33003c27 <redacted> + 1806,
8   UIKit                               0x3300347d <redacted> + 184,
9   UIKit                               0x32f29d59 <redacted> + 380,
10  QuartzCore                          0x32ba762b <redacted> + 142,
11  QuartzCore                          0x32ba2e3b <redacted> + 350,
12  QuartzCore                          0x32ba2ccd <redacted> + 16,
13  QuartzCore                          0x32ba26df <redacted> + 230,
14  QuartzCore                          0x32ba24ef <redacted> + 314,
15  UIKit                               0x32f2d3e1 <redacted> + 8232,
16  CoreFoundation                      0x306d820b <redacted> + 14,
17  CoreFoundation                      0x306d76db <redacted> + 206,
18  CoreFoundation                      0x306d5ecf <redacted> + 622,
19  CoreFoundation                      0x30640ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522,
20  CoreFoundation                      0x30640ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106,
21  GraphicsServices                    0x35546663 GSEventRunModal + 138,
22  UIKit                               0x32f8d14d UIApplicationMain + 1136,
23  CodeI                               0x00059c1d main + 116,
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x3b39dab7 <redacted> + 2
)
```

Since this I have read a post that said putting the objects into a NSArray of Dictionaries like I am will cause the error as when coredata trys to populate the Array it needs to be in its native object.

So I have since changed my read method to this.

```
- (NSArray *)readManuf
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Test listing all FailedBankInfos from the store
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Manuf" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    NSError *error = nil;


    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    return fetchedObjects;
}
```

which returns the MutableArray of native objects. However, when I try to use this array of native objects it still dose not populate at any point.

Comment: I have seen this occurs when someone has an NSManagedObject which has not faulted yet and then in some other part of the application deletes that data from the database.  It would then cause the object to not be able to fault in its data.  See if it is possible that a part of your app deletes a row from core data while another part is holding a reference of non faulted objects.

Comment: okay ill look for an instance like this. thanks thought maybe i was doing something wrong... well wrong..er... ;)

Comment: Your second code block returns the immutable array fetchedObjects while the mutable manufacturingDictionaryArray should cause a static analyzer warning because it's unused.